# Python: type() gives blank result

Tags: python, types

What does it mean when I do

```
print type(foo)
```

and get absolutely nothing?

foo is the response from an eBay REST search query, and it's supposed to be XML according to the eBay docs.  When I

```
print foo
```

I get stuff -- a long string of values about ebay items all butted-up against one another.

Comment: Try a bit of debugging. try, print type(''), print len(foo), print dir(foo)

Comment: Also `print type`. It might have been inadvertantly overridden.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means `type` is a function or other callable object that returns an empty string. Since the built-in function doesn't do that, you have most likely called another function `type()`. Change the name of that function to something else. `type_()` is good. Or `_type()`, or `somethingtype()`.

Comment: If `type` was a function returning `None` then print would output `None`. It sounds more likely `type` is a function returning an empty string.

Comment: @Duncan: Ah, sorry, I didn't read the question very carefully, and got in my head that the first example was without a "print". So you are correct. I updated.